# CORS Issue in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, service, cors

I have an *Angular application* in which I need to call to a service, located in a different server using `POST` method.

It fails and gives the following error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '...' is therefore not allowed access

I have tried to set the header using the follwoing

```
const headers = new Headers();
headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```

but it doesn't solves the problem.

> When I try to access it using CORS chrome plugin **'Allow-Control-Allow-Orign: *'** and **CORS Toggle**, then it works properly.

Please have a look at [**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/m8Wh6XIt6ROYTyHVEeu5?p=preview), specifically in the following files:

a) *src/test/test.component.ts* (where service has been consumed)

b) *src/test/test.service.ts* (where service has been defined)

> **Note:**
>
> 1) I have used the end point as https://wwww.google.co.in, just for an
>   example.
>
> 2) The CORS issue is needed to be handled in **frontend only**.

Answer (score 2):

Do this on the back end:-

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        var enableCorsAttribute = new EnableCorsAttribute("*",
                                           "Origin, Content-Type, Accept",
                                           "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");

        config.EnableCors(enableCorsAttribute);

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot modify the backend and need to modify it from Frontend only.

Comment: For CORS server changes are required..you can refer to the following article and opt for other options https://daveceddia.com/access-control-allow-origin-cors-errors-in-angular/

Comment: It does work when used with the Chrome plugin. So I believe the server must have handled CORS issue.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the right to send POST requests to the server, so in your real example, you have to give access to your angularJs application, you can see by that https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

Comment: It does work when used with the Chrome plugin. So I believe the server must have handled CORS issue.